# SQL Query to print Y if value from one table is present in other

Tags: sql, sql-server

Happy New Year!!

I am using SQL Server I have three tables. Employee, EmployeeVeteran and VeteranBranch:

```
    Employee
    ------------------------
    EmployeeId     Name
    ------------------------
    1001           Adams
    1002           Jacobs
    1003           Peter
    1004           Nancy

    EmployeeVeteran
    ---------------------------------
    EmployeeVeteranId    EmployeeID  BranchId
    ---------------------------------
    1                    1002        1
    2                    1004        2

    VeteranBranch
    ---------------------------------
    BranchId    BranchName
    ---------------------------------
    1           Air Force
    2           Army
```

I need to write a SQL Query to get me data in following format:

```
    ------------------------------------------------
    EmployeeId     Name         IsVeteran     Branch
    ------------------------------------------------
    1001           Adams        N             NULL
    1002           Jacobs       Y             Air Force
    1003           Peter        N             NULL
    1004           Nancy        Y             Army
```

Can you please suggest how can I do this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Check out LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a `left join`.  It is important to "chain" them together:

```
select e.EmployeeId, e.Name,
       (case when ev.EmployeeVeteranId is null then 'N' else 'Y' end) as IsVeteran,
       vb.BranchName
from employee e left join
     employeeveteran ev
     on ev.EmployeeVeteranId = e.EmployeeVeteranId left join
     VeteranBranch vb
     on vb.BranchId = ev.BranchId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Switch Case** Statement with **Left Join** as below

```
SELECT 
    E.EmployeeID,
    E.Name,
    CASE ISNULL(VB.BranchName,'') WHEN '' THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' END AS IsVeteran,
    VB.BranchName AS Branch
FROM Employee E
LEFT JOIN EmployeeVeteran EV ON E.EmployeeID=EV.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN VeteranBranch VB ON EV.BranchID=VB.BranchID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with code...

```
Select E.EmployeeID,E.Name,Case When EV.VeteranID IS NOT NULL Then 'Y' Else 'N' END AS IsVeteran,VB.BranchName
From Employee E
LEFT JOIN EmployeeVeteran EV
On E.EmployeeID = EV.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN VeteranBranch VB
On EV.BranchID = VB.BranchID
```